# “Could not update; currently locked” using MS-Access OleDb

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, oledb

I've already checked the code for non-closing connections, still I got this error in production:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not update; currently locked.
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  at (my code here)
```

Looks like theres a recursive call at ExecuteNonQuery() we can see at the bottom of the stack. Is it a retry pattern? Any thoughts?

Additional info:

- Could not reproduce the error in my environment. Also tried to reproduce it with load tests without success.
- About 40 minutes after the app was published, I received this kind of error from different clients (tought different clients does't share the same database) After that I was forced to rollback because of the mass deadlock.
- All the error stacks have some recursivity (it happens at Command.ExecuteNonQuery or Connection.Open).
- Usually the "currently locked" message provides the name of the user that got the database locked, but this specific message doesn't.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653753.aspx#access_database

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but change the datasource is not a short term option, I could really use a help with this error.

Comment: You took care to state that you checked for non-closing connections, but otherwise you don't share the overall context.  Would it be useful to see the query text or other details about what you're doing?  If it says its locked, then perhaps it really is locked elsewhere and you just did not notice it yet.  The ExecuteNonQuery() recursion is interesting, but may have nothing to do with the error.

Comment: And technically, an open connection does not necessarily lock a table, nor lock rows (conceding of course that no open connections should mean no locks).  What about some good, old-fashion debugging by placing a breakpoint before the query execution, then purposefully opening the database in Access or another process and executing the same query.  Do you get the same error?  This could at least help narrow down whether it is locked by some other means, or if the error is derived only from the call stack you show.

Comment: It happened mostlly with single column update commands, and also with connection open before the query event started

Comment: All I can think of is I/O issue (would be really helpful to take a look at the OleDb source code) or a specific thread abort is happening somewhere in the code, prevend some command to end properly just couldn't figure out yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by many slow queries, concurrence and error within the data provider.

The [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/) saved my life this time. It's the best tool I know to trace down problems in production environments.